# Running after night shift?

Tags: running, weight-loss, body-fat

I am working the night shift and I usually go for a run after that at about 6 'o'clock in the morning. I don't feel fresh because of the whole night stretch.

But the problem is I desperately want to remove my belly fat and other extra fats so I force myself to run.

My question is: if I only have that time available and I want to reduce the fat in 1 month is it advisable to exercise this way? If this isn't healthy, what should I do instead?

Also I have seen many people running for years but still having a lot of fat, which makes me depressed.

So what is the correct way of exercising or any diet so that I can remove my fat in one month.

Comment: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/8259/3778 is has an answer on the rate of fat-loss

Answer (score 2):

> if I only have that time available and I want to reduce the fat in 1
>   month is it advisable to exercise this way?

If that truly is the only time available, it definitely is better than no exercise at all.
However, if you are truly dedicated, you should be able to wake up earlier than you usually do and exercise.

> Also I have seen many people running for years but still having a lot
>   of fat, which makes me depressed.

Most likely, the people you speak of either a) don't exercise properly b)maintain poor diet c)both. I'm not judging these people, but you shouldn't compare yourself to them if you want to be in better shape.

> So what is the correct way of exercising or any diet so that I can
>   remove my fat in one month.

That is an open-ended question. Run a few google searches and remember the golden rule: Keep It Simple.

Answer (score 0):

I found running after work, but before dinner very effective for years.  If I waited too long, or ate dinner first, it was much harder to run.

So consider running first thing, after your night shift ends?  See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think if there is a balance between your eating habits and Exercise, I mean if you are on a proper healthy diet and do exercise accordingly obviously you can reduce your fat. Those who can't do it because sometimes they do only one thing and fail to do another one.

Comment: I don't really get what you want to say in the last sentence.